# a doubt on transformation on space of probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose, $X$ is some measurable space, $\mu$ is a probability measure on it, could anyone explain to me how the following is a map or transformation on $\mathcal M_1(X)$ (space of all probability measure on $X$)? Also, in this case, what is $T$ on Suppose, $X$ is some measurable space, $\mu$ is a probability measure on it, could anyone explain to me how the following is a map or transformation on $\mathcal M_1(X)$ (space of all probability measure on $X$)?

$T(\mu)(A)=\mu(T^{-1}(A)$? now my doubt is $T$ acting as a function on $\mathcal M_1(X) $, which one is varying here as an input? $A$ or $\mu$? or both? where $A\in B(X)$, $B(X)$  is all Borel sets of $X$. Thanks! 
?

Also, what is the transformation $T$ on $\mathcal M_1(X)$ , in this case? $T(A)=\mu(T^{-1}(A)$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is assumed to be a measurable transformation in the sense $T^{-1}(A)$  is  a measurable set whenever $A$ is a measurable set. Given any probability measure $\mu$ you define  a new probability measure $\nu$ by $\nu(A) =\mu (T^{-1}(A))$. The induced transformation is defined by $T_*(\mu)=\nu$. It maps probability measures to probability measures.

Comment: now from this definition of $\nu$ what is the definition of invariant probability measures? $\nu(A) =\mu (T^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)\forall A$, something like this?

Comment: @miosaki Exactly. Invariance means $\mu =\nu$.

Comment: I stil dont understand the role of $T_*$ in the discussion above screenshot.

Comment: did you mean $T_*$ as an induced transformation?

Comment: @miosaki By an abuse of notation they are writing $T$ for $T_{*}$ also.

Comment: So, let me be clear: $T: X\to X$ is a measurable map.  $\mu$ a prob measure, $\nu(A)=\mu(T^{-1}(A))$, now  $T_*(\mu)=\nu$, is a map on the space of probability measure, invariant prob measures are those, for which $T_* \mu=\mu$.

Comment: @miosaki Yes, that is right.